# how to change the html tags into html entities using PHP

Tags: php, html, entity

This is a simple question. I am using the libmail class to send my mails. For composing the mails I am using the CKEditor. My problem is that when I send the mail to someone the mail is displaying like this:

```
<p><span style="color: rgb(255, 160, 122);">data</span></p>
```

I already tried this:

```
$message = htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($message));
```

And:

```
$message =  htmlentities($message);
```

Still it does the same thing.

Comment: You didn't format your code properly when you posted it (I cant see it)

Comment: How do you send that email? In plain text or in HTML?

Comment: Are you sure you specify the mail's Content-Type as text/html, or at least for that specific part of the MIME?

Comment: Meena, are you sure you do understand what you want? htmlspecialchars DOES change html tags into html entities. And in HTML representation it would look as raw HTML, not rendered.

Comment: Content-Type as text/html - i changed the statement now its working fine thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looking at that class, I see a Html method.
So if you want to add HTML with charset UTF-8, use:

```
$mail = new Mail;
$mail->To('receiver@example.com');
$mail->Html('<b>boldfaced</b>', 'UTF-8');
$mail->Send();
```

Comment: i am using the "libmail_161php5.php"

Comment: if i change the  $mail->Body('<b>boldfaced</b>', 'UTF-8'); into $mail->Html('<b>boldfaced</b>', 'UTF-8');
 my mail is not  sending Is there is any other way to solve this

Answer (score 0):

Try `html_entity_decode` http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php